# Loop Algorithm design

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop

Hi i written a code to draw a circles using putpixel method in java.
i tried to design a loop for this code but i didn't success.
This is the original code:

```
g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
    int x=200, y=200,rad =120;
    printcircle(x,y,rad,g); 
    printcircle(x+rad/2,y,rad/2,g);
    printcircle(x-rad/2,y,rad/2,g);
    printcircle(200-90,200,30,g);
    printcircle(200+90,200,30,g);
    printcircle(200-30,200,30,g);
    printcircle(200+30,200,30,g);
    printcircle(200+45,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200-45,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200+15,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200-15,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200-15,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200-75,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200+75,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200+105,200,15,g);
    printcircle(200-105,200,15,g);
```

Where rad stands for radius and x,y is the center point for circles.
this is the shape that i had written my code for it

[image]

and this is the code that i had start to code it with loop:

```
g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
    int x=200, y=200,rad =120;
    printcircle(x,y,rad,g);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {  int t=rad/2;
     printcircle(x+t,y,t,g);
      printcircle(x-t,y,t,g);
      }
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 { 
     int t=rad/4;
     printcircle(200-90,200,30,g);
       printcircle(200+90,200,30,g);
       printcircle(200-30,200,30,g);
         printcircle(200+30,200,30,g);
 }  
          printcircle(200+45,200,15,g);
           printcircle(200-45,200,15,g);
            printcircle(200+15,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200-15,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200-15,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200-75,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200+75,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200+105,200,15,g);
             printcircle(200-105,200,15,g);
```

If anyone can help me please.

Comment: is this how they design those frilly undergarments? xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
int x=200, y=200,rad =120;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   int param;
   if(i == 2 || i == 6)
      param = 30;
   else if(i == 4)
      param = 60;
   else if(i == 0)
      param = 120;
   else
      param = 15;
   printcircle(x+i*15,y,param,g);
   if(i == 0)
      continue;
   printcircle(x-i*15,y,param,g);
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained why your approach is superior and fixes the problem described in the question. Code only questions are technically ok, but don't have the same quality level as a fully explained answer